# Link a Student Name to the Student Custom Object in LWC SalesForce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-object, salesforcedx-cli

When I created the LWC components it contains the Student Name with his grade
I want to allow the user when he clicks on the Student Name to be redirected to the student record in Student Custom Object.

Comment: use navigation mixing

Answer (score 1):

You have to import NavigationMixin:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
```

Add to the extension when you declare your LWC class:

```
export default class *yourclassname* extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
```

Then, navigate to the record page:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
         recordId: 'recordId of sobject you want to navigate to',
         objectApiName: 'api name of sobject',
         actionName: 'view'
    }
})
```